# Emptying Windows 8 AppCache

Tags: windows-store-apps, wininet, html5-appcache, application-cache

My Windows 8 Store App uses [AppCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767297.aspx) to cache web resources. For testing purposes, I need to be able to empty or invalidate the entire cache from a separate application. Simply purging my WinINET cache (e.g. from Fiddler) doesn't delete my application's files, because in Win8 each application gets an isolated cache.

I have found that I can empty the cache from within my application by creating a new cache and swapping the existing one with that, but I need to be able to do this from a separate application. Scouring MSDN, I haven't been able to come up with a method for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this. I think the easiest will be to use [Protocol Activation].

Make a protocol similar to `clearmyapp://`, then have your app, on activation by that protocol, clear the cache then close itself. Then you can create a shortcut on your desktop or a script that will call `clearmyapp://`.

The harder way would be to create a script that finds your app's folder in the Packages folder (in Users/*Username*/Local/Packages/PackageName), then finding the cache contents and deleting them.